# Implementing Haskell's `unwords`

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#loading-modules) explains the `unwords` function.

> $unwords ["hey","there","mate"]
>     "hey there mate"

Here's my implementation.

```
unwords' :: [String] -> String
unwords' [] = []
unwords' (x:xs)
  | null xs   = x
  | otherwise = x ++ " " ++ unwords' xs
```

Is there a possible implementation with `fold`? I tried the following, but the `" "` got appended to the end.

```
$foldr (\x acc -> x ++ " " ++ acc) [] ["hey", "there", "mate"]  
"hey there mate "
```

Also, how can I append a `String([Char])` to another String without `++`?

Lastly, please critique in general.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `foldr` solution doesn't work because it's using the empty list you're passing in the final step. You can use [`foldr1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3afoldr1) instead, it uses the final element of the list in place of being passed an accumulator value.

Looking to the `fold`s to implement `unwords` isn't a bad idea, but there are other high-level functions that you can use to write a more terse or readable version. Let's start from a verbal description of what `unwords` is doing.

> Insert a space character between every `String` in a list, then join the resulting `String`s together.

The latter half of that description is easy, we know that `String` is really `[Char]`, and we can easily flatten doubly-nested lists with `concat`. The former portion we could implement on our own, or search [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for to see if anything already exists in the `Prelude` or other modules that could help us out. In this case, we're looking for a function with the type `a -> [a] -> [a]`, that is, we want to pass it a value and a list and have it return a list with that value inserted between each pair of elements. As luck would have it, there's a function in `Data.List` that does exactly what we're looking for called `intersperse` that comes up as the first result if we perform that search.

Using these two functions, we can write a very short version of `unwords` that reads almost like prose.

```
import Data.List (intersperse)
import Prelude hiding (unwords)

unwords :: [String] -> String
unwords = concat . intersperse " "
```

Besides the aesthetic appeal of this solution, to me this illustrates the power of thinking about *what* you want to do in Haskell, instead of thinking about *how* it's going to be done.

Comment: thanks for your thoughtful answer, bisserlis. Such a powerful 1 liner for `unwords` that you've provided.

Answer (score 2):

The `otherwise` case is redundant.

```
unwords' :: [String] -> String
unwords' [] = []
unwords' (x:xs) = x ++ " " ++ unwords' xs
```

To use a fold but not get the extra space, use `foldr1`:

```
unwords'' :: [String] -> String
unwords'' xs
  | null xs   = []
  | otherwise = foldr1 (\x acc -> x ++ ' ' : acc) xs
```

Comment: In the 2nd implementation, I observe your first guard: `null xs = []`. However, are you concerned that `foldr1` can throw a run-time exception if that check was **not** there? Looking at code that depends on a sequence (example: getting a value from an Option in Scala) seems fitting for a monad, [no](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVXt1RG_yN0&feature=youtu.be)? My concern with `foldr1` -http://stackoverflow.com/q/23183935/409976. P.S. I've used monads a bit in Scala, but I'm still new to them.

Comment: Yes, that's why the `null xs` guard is there.

Answer (score 1):

The original implementation isn’t ideal, because it’s recursive without being tail-recursive or tail-recursive-modulo-cons (two special cases that GHC can optimize).  Other answers have already discussed how to fix up the `foldr` implementation, which would be more efficient.

This code could also be cleaned up with pattern-matching:

```
unwords' [] = []
unwords' (x:xs)
  | null xs   = x
  | otherwise = x ++ " " ++ unwords' xs
```

could become:

```
unwords' []     = []
unwords' [x]    = x
unwords' (x:xs) = x ++ " " ++ unwords' xs
```

Another efficient technique in functional programming is a map-reduction.  In this case, you can represent adding a single character in front of each word after the first as a `:` operation, then concatenate them, which lets you write this as:

```
unwords2 :: [String] -> String
unwords2 []     = []
unwords2 (x:xs) = x ++ (concatMap (' ':) xs)
```

That should be “well-behaved” enough for the compiler, in some cases, to optimize away deep copies of the words you pass in.

Testing on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9oEfq1WGh) shows what code you actually get with both versions, and allows you to see the intermediate representation of both.  The original version gets transformed into:

```
unwords'
  = \ ds_dJs ->
      case ds_dJs of {
        [] -> [];
        : x_agY xs_agZ ->
          case xs_agZ of wild1_a13X {
            [] -> x_agY;
            : ds1_a13Y ds2_a13Z ->
              ++ x_agY (unpackAppendCString# lvl1_r15Z (unwords' wild1_a13X))
          }
      }
```

Which as you see is making redundant deep copies with `unpackAppendCString` of each nested recursive call.  The second version becomes:

```
test2_go1
  = \ ds1_a151 ->
      case ds1_a151 of {
        [] -> [];
        : y_a154 ys_a155 -> ++_$s++ ds_r160 y_a154 (test2_go1 ys_a155)
      }
end Rec }

unwords2
  = \ ds1_dIN ->
      case ds1_dIN of {
        [] -> [];
        : x_aHm xs_aHn -> ++ x_aHm (test2_go1 xs_aHn)
      }
```

where the `concatMap` call becomes a helper function that reduces to a builtin. Introducing calls to these functions as top-level variables shows that GHC is capable of partially inlining the second version but not the first.

Although, in the real world, if you care about optimized string-processing, you would use a `Text` or a `ByteString`, not a linear linked list of UCS-4 `[Char]`.

Comment: Older question than I realized when I answered, but I hope this is valuable to someone who finds it.

Answer (score 0):

Here the shortest version I could come up with:

```
unwords = tail . (>>= (' ' :))
```

Remember that `>>=` is just `concatMap` for lists. So this code prepends every `String` in the list with a space, concats it and than throws the very first character (the leading space) away using `tail`.